# what does "place to be" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/-ygExIZm7Wo). It is at around 9 minute and 56 second. Here is the context:

> This all means: more fat synthesis, less fat burning, and less energy production. If you are a human with things to do and **places to be**, this is not so great.

Does this simply mean with places to live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the entire phrase "*things to do and places to be*" that you need to understand the meaning of.

This is an English idiom, and it basically means you are busy.

It would normally be used like this:

> I have things to do and places to be.

Some people may also instead say *places to go*.

Usually it also carries an undertone of *impatience*; that is it may be said to someone who is wasting your time. For example:

> Can you hurry up? I have things to do and places to be.

In your example it is used in a slightly different and interesting way. Rather than expressing impatience with somebody else, the writer is using a familiar idiom to describe the reader as a busy person who can't afford to follow a diet/exercise regime that will leave them with too little energy to get things done.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means that you **have a busy life**.

You don't just sit at home all day, you have to be at some places (at work/at a bar hanging out with friends, etc.)